# i can't use DataBindingUtil.setContentView() with kotlin

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, data-binding, android-databinding

when i want to start new activity named DetailActivity my app will `crash.`
this is my error:

```
      E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
            Process: com.example.notepad, PID: 4793
            android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
                at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
                at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getText(ResourcesWrapper.java:54)
                at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3888)
                at com.example.notepad.databinding.ActivityDetailBindingImpl.executeBindings(ActivityDetailBindingImpl.java:115)
                at androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.executeBindingsInternal(ViewDataBinding.java:473)
                at androidx.databinding.ViewDataBinding.executePendingBindings(ViewDataBinding.java:445)
        ...
```

I think it is related to `setContentView`. Because when i use common `setContentView` program works well but when i use `DataBindingUtil.setContentView()` my app `crashs.` this is `DetailActivity`:

```
    import android.content.Context
    import android.content.Intent
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil
    import com.example.notepad.databinding.ActivityDetailBinding

    class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        private lateinit var binding: ActivityDetailBinding
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_detail)


            if(intent != null) {
                binding.nameText.text = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_NAME)
               binding.ageText.text = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_AGE)
            }

        }
```

and this is `activity_detail`:

```
    <layout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        >
        <data>
            <variable
                name="person"
                type="com.example.notepad.Person" />
        </data>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".DetailActivity">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{person.name}"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/age_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{person.age}"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </layout>
```

this is person class:

```
class Person(var name: String , var age: Int)
```

[update]
my ActivityDetailBindingImpl file is in java while i am using kolin. maybe problem is about this.

Comment: Could you post the code for `com.example.notepad.Person` pls? from the stack trace it looks like you're setting the text view's text to a resource that doesn't exist - 0 to be precise. I can only see this possible if `Person.name` or `Person.age` are integers. I'm guessing the `age` is?

Comment: post update. person is a simple class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted in my comment, the problem should be with the class `class Person(var name: String, var age: Int)` and the binding in the xml:

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/age_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{person.age}"/>
```

`android:text="@{person.age}"` the databinding framework will search for a method `setText` in `TextView` that takes one argument of type `person.age.class` which is `Int`. This method is this [one](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(int)) and as you can see it expects a resource id.

This means that the text view will try to look up a string with id matching the value of `Person.age` which according to your stack trace doesn't exist.

To fix this, either change the type of `age` to `String` use another approach in the binding such like:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/age_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@{String.valueOf(person.age)}"/>
```

Comment: i can't use toString like your answer .i get this error: cannot find identifire "toString()"